# How can I get the date when Nexus created artifact?

Tags: nexus

I am trying to pull the date of artifact created at nexus using rest api or using any other option. But I couldnt find. could someone help me?

Comment: What NXRM version?

Comment: @joedragons OSS 3.13.0-01

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you created https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-18303 which IMO was the right call, I don't think this information is currently accessible via NXRM3 rest.

You can see this via the UI, in both search and tree browse via the "Blob created" field.